# What is optimal way of passing 100 objects in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have two Activity in application i,e Main Activity and Details Activity.
Main Activity has recycler view which is displaying 100 objects.

Details activity has View Pager which is hosting fragment.My fragment has two textview which is displaying data from the main activity.

On Click of any Item in Main Activity, Details Activity is started with the complete details of the Object inside the fragment.

Details Activity has fragment which can be swiped left and right.
To make it work I am passing all 100 objects with on Click event of recycler view .

I want to show details of next object when I swipe left or right without going to MainActivity.

In my case I have all the 100 objects in Detail Activity, So I can swipe left or right but I wont feel it is optimal way.

Is there any way I can achieve this design in more optimal way.

Comment: I recommend you read **[what topics you can ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)** and then **[how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**, next **[how to create Minimal, Complete and Verifable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Then edit your question accordingly to attract more attention.

Comment: Save your objects to an SQLite Database or Realm. Pass around only IDs, those are lightweight.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Even If I passed the id only , again  I need to pass the 100 ids.

Comment: Post your code in order to optimize

Comment: @aks 100 `int`s is nothing - just add them to your `Intent` bundle, and retrieve them with [`Bundle#getIntArray`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BaseBundle.html#getIntArray(java.lang.String)). 100 objects isn't all that much either to be honest.

Comment: Yes you need to pass around the IDs so you know what to show BUT parceling an array of integers rather than an array of objects is so much more efficient in terms of speed and more importantly memory.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest in your case you should open a fragment for details rather passing 100 objects and load that details in a view pager(Your activity will  be holding Adapters and those adapter will be carrying your 100 objects information). By view pager, you can swipe to load the details of next object. Hope that helps you

Comment: And when I levae the activity and come back the data will be lost. You don't want to put 100 objects in Saved State.

Comment: this case was not defined in actual question.

Comment: This case is implied if you aim to produce apps of quality higher than a school project.